# ps -C behavior changed between Centos 6 and Centos 8

Tags: centos, ps

Our system often uses `ps -C cmdName` to check if a process is running and, if not, restart it.

In moving from Centos 6 to Centos 8 it seems the behavior of `ps -C` has changed which broke much of our system.

**Centos 6 (32-bit)**

Yes, process is there:

```
# ps aux | grep DvBuildSegmentList
root     16223  4.0  0.1  16064 11272 pts/0    S    14:14   0:00 ./DvBuildSegmentList
root     16264  0.0  0.0   4416  1880 pts/0    S+   14:14   0:00 grep DvBuildSegmentList
```

And `ps -C` on full command name detects the process:

```
# ps -C DvBuildSegmentList
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
16223 pts/0    00:00:00 DvBuildSegmentL
```

(note truncated command line in output)

**Centos 8 (64-bit)**

Yes, process is there:

```
# ps aux | grep DvBuildSeg
root     15282  0.9  0.2  99796 42424 pts/1    S    14:18   0:04 ./DvBuildSegmentList
root     16989  0.0  0.0 221900  1104 pts/1    S+   14:26   0:00 grep --color=auto DvBuildSeg
```

Using full command name has no output:

```
# /bin/ps -C DvBuildSegmentList
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

But using a shortened command name does detect the process:

```
# /bin/ps -C DvBuildSegmentL
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
15282 pts/1    00:00:06 DvBuildSegmentL
```

We need to maintain both the 32-bit Centos 6 and the 64-bit Centos 8, ideally without re-writing a lot of code.

1. Is there a way to get the same behavior of `ps` between versions? (might not be able to truncate the command name to the first 15 characters because of name collisions)
2. Is there another approach to detect the process?  (There's a lot of code and the `ps -C` approach is sprinkled across C++, perl, php, and bash)

**EDIT I**

For what its worth, the content of `/proc/<pid>/stat` shows the truncated file name:

```
cat /proc/4605/stat
4605 (DvBuildSegmentL) S 25769 4605 25769 34817 4605 1077936384 10536 304 0 0 225 119 0 0 20 0 1 0 6717759 103620608 10945 18446744073709551615 4194304 4339868 140734307933616 0 0 0 0 4096 16901 1 0 0 17 4 0 0 0 0 0 6438088 6440229 11730944 140734307937640 140734307937666 140734307937666 140734307938275 0
```

However, `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` does have the full command name albeit with the full path prepended to it

```
cat -v /proc/4605/cmdline
/usr/local/blah/blah/blah/DvBuildSegmentList^@-d^@2^@
```

Comment: As you have found, `ps` varies a lot between implementations. I recommend you to stick with the options listed in the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html) if you want to keep portability. `-C` is not among them.

Comment: `pgrep` is more reliable than `ps`. Pid files are more reliable than either. Open files are more reliable than either. I don't know why the behavior of `ps` has changed. The truncation at 15 bytes comes from `/proc/$pid/stat`, but I don't know why `ps -C` would check that and not the command line from `/proc/$pid/cmdline`.

Comment: `pgrep` behaves the same. `DvBuildSegmentL` is detected but anything longer is not found.

Answer (score 1):

One way I envision to work around this difference is to rebuild CentOS 6's version of `procps` package then `yum swap` from `procps-ng` to it. Not the safest approach, that will replace quite a handful of system programs with their older version.

So you might want to rebuild `procps` under a completely different name and having it install only `ps`, to e.g. `/opt/el6-rebuilds/bin/ps`. You would then ensure that the containing directory is on the system `PATH`, via `/etc/profile.d` facility.
The result would be "equivalent to CentOS 6" `ps` version used in CentOS 8.

But all that saying, are you sure of that difference? Just tried it on my RHEL 8 and `ps -C <program name>` works just fine, when specified exactly  (you actually say the opposite, that it only works when specified via partial string).

Comment: Did you check with a name truncated to exactly 15 characters? That's the process name recorded in `/proc/$pid/stat` and some tools check that. A test with a different substring would not be conclusive.

Comment: Just checked. `/proc/<pid>/stat` shows the truncated file name. Details added to the question above.

Comment: Also note that `/proc/<pid>/stat` shows truncated command name in RHEL7 and earlier. Perhaps that's where the real "bug" is.

Answer (score 1):

These two approaches seem to work across OS versions:

**grep for process name**

`ps aux | grep myLongProcessName | grep -v`

returns 0 if the process is running and 1 if the process is not found.  The second `grep -v` is needed because sometimes (but not always) the `grep` command itself appears in the output of `grep myLongProcessName`.

**Send signal 0 via killall**

`killall -0 myLongProcessName`

returns `0` if the process exists and `1` if the process is not found.

The "double `grep`" approach fails if `myLongProcessName` is, in fact, a substring of another process.  eg. If we have three processes:

- `longProcessDBAccess` (not running)
- `longProcessDBAccessManager` (running)
- `longProcessDBAccessClient` (running)

Using the "double `grep`" approach to check if `longProcessDBAccess` is running will fail because it also picks up the existence of the other two.

However, for the `killall` approach to work, the `uid` of the processing running `killall` must have permission to do so.

[kill](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html):

> The `kill()` function shall send a signal to a process or a group of
> processes specified by `pid`. The signal to be sent is specified by `sig`
> and is either one from the list given in `<signal.h>` or 0. If `sig` is 0
> (the null signal), error checking is performed but no signal is
> actually sent. The null signal can be used to check the validity of
> `pid`.
>
> For a process to have permission to send a signal to a process
> designated by `pid`, unless the sending process has appropriate
> privileges, the real or effective user ID of the sending process shall
> match the real or saved set-user-ID of the receiving process.

Comment: _If you're certain that there are no competing process names,_ here's a third way: truncate your search string to 15 chars: `ps -fC ${pname:0:15}`. Also you should be aware that your muscle memory took over when you tried to type `killall -0 myLongProcessName` - oops!

Comment: Offered edit for review to correct the obvious typo, should be `killall -0 myLongProcessName` not `killall -9 myLongProcessName`. Had to add some pointless harmless edits elsewhere to make the silly 6 character quota.